# Should there be an optional community guideline quiz in the FAQ that can earn a badge or rep?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am starting to notice a huge plethora of bad questions. Mostly ones involving "write this program for me" or where can I find information for... (something that can easily be googled.) So I just thought to make the rules more clear, new users if they choose to can take a guideline quiz that is found in the FAQ, and upon passing they can either earn a badge or small amount of reputation. Of course the quiz can only be done once. If you think the idea is superfluous, feel free to let me know. I don't care if you down vote it. I just think it would be a good way to make the rules more clear to new users with incentive and put them to a good start. What are your opinions?

Comment: A lot of first time users **discover this site** / come here when looking for quick solutions. A quiz will discourage them from joining the site as it will be time consuming, distracting them from whatever task they were doing and they will take their problem elsewhere. Or so i think.

Comment: As I said it is optional, they go there themselves by going to the faq if they choose. Not force them to do it when creating an account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already the [Analytical](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1306/analytical) bronze badge, which one earns after visiting every section of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com).

Now, I know what you're thinking. This isn't the same as taking a quiz. Well, you're right, it isn't. But at the same time, visiting every section of the FAQ to earn this badge is actually a little more challenging than you thought it was, I'm sure!

If you don't visit every section just right, you don't get the badge. Now, this isn't the same as taking a quiz on the FAQ, but my bet is that if you spend enough time in the FAQ trying to expand every section and click on every single link to be 100% sure you've seen it all, something will happen to your brain where, even though you may not have the FAQ memorized, you most likely know what part of the FAQ to look at to find a piece of information.

In this day and age, it's more important to know where to look to find the answer than it is to have something memorized that will one day become obsolete and take you with it. ;)

Plus, a quiz is just going too far. If someone posts something that needs to be closed, we'll just close it and leave them a nice comment with some tips on how to maybe edit the post to get it reopened. :)

Comment: I can attest that the mechanics of the badge do their best to ensure that the person actually _read_ the FAQ. It's not just expanding all the sections and calling it a day.

Comment: @TinyTimPost - Aha! So that retina detection technology that follows your eye on the screen is now in place. Now we're all in trouble! Maybe that's what Apple means when they say "Retina display"

Comment: Well, when the badge was implemented I thought it would be a travesty if a moderator _didn't_ have it, so I went through and expanded everything then waited. A few days later I went through and re-read the darn thing, and finally got the badge.

Comment: @TinyTimPost - I did the same on PMSE! Especially considering about 15 other users already had the badge. ;)

Comment: @jmort253 actually it's Samsung that have that: the Galaxy S3 turns on when you look at it :S